# how to call getReadableDatabase outside of SQLiteOpenHelper

Tags: android, sqlite

I've separated the construction of my dataBase and the request on it in two classes in my projet :

The database :

public class SQLiteBase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
private static final String TABLE = "dataOne";
private static final String COL_ID = "ID";
private static final String COL_CONTENT = "CONTENT";

private static final String CREATE_BDD =
        "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE + " ("
        + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + COL_CONTENT + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

public SQLiteBase(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_BDD);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE " + TABLE + ";");
    onCreate(db);
}}
```

and the Data worker :

public class SQLiteWorker {

```
private static final int VERSION_BDD = 1;
private static final String NOM_BDD = "sharedOne.db";


private static final String TABLE = "dataOne";
private static final String COL_ID = "ID";
private static final int NUM_COL_ID = 0;
private static final String COL_CONTENT = "CONTENT";
private static final int NUM_COL_CONTENT = 1;

private SQLiteDatabase bdd;

private SQLiteBase sqLiteBase;

public SQLiteWorker(Context context){
    sqLiteBase = new SQLiteBase(context, NOM_BDD, null, VERSION_BDD);
}

public void open(){
    //on ouvre la BDD en écriture
    bdd = sqLiteBase.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void close(){
    //on ferme l'accès à la BDD
    bdd.close();
}

public SQLiteDatabase getBDD(){
    return bdd;
}

public long insertDate(DataOne data){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COL_CONTENT, data.getContent());
    return bdd.insert(TABLE, null, values);
}

public int updateData(int id, DataOne data){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COL_CONTENT, data.getContent());
    return bdd.update(TABLE, values, COL_ID + " = " +id, null);
}
public int removeDataWithID(int id){
    return bdd.delete(TABLE, COL_ID + " = " +id, null);
}
public DataOne cursorToDataOne(Cursor c){
    DataOne data = new DataOne();
    data.setContent(c.getString(NUM_COL_CONTENT));
    data.setId(c.getInt(NUM_COL_ID));
    return data;
}

public DataOne getDataOneWithId(int id){
    Cursor c = bdd.query(TABLE, new String[]{COL_ID, COL_CONTENT}, COL_ID + " = \"" + id + "\"", null, null, null, null);
    return cursorToDataOne(c);

}



public static Cursor getDatas(String id, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    SQLiteQueryBuilder sqliteQueryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    sqliteQueryBuilder.setTables(TABLE);

    if(id != null) {
        sqliteQueryBuilder.appendWhere("_id" + " = " + id);
    }

    if(sortOrder == null || sortOrder == "") {
        sortOrder = COL_ID;
    }
    Cursor cursor = sqliteQueryBuilder.query(getReadableDatabase(),
            projection,
            selection,
            selectionArgs,
            null,
            null,
            sortOrder);
    return cursor;
}}
```

And in my function getDatas I need to call `getReadableDatabase()` , but I can't call that method directly because my class doesn't extends SQLiteOpenHelper (since I'm getting the instance of my database instead of working directly on it). But the fact is that i can't do `mybase.getReadableDatabase` since the method isn't static. What is the way to read my dataBase with getReadableDatabase in another class?

Comment: Why are you making getDatas static? Is there any specific reason for that?

Comment: It was just for a test, it won't be static in the end

Comment: So you can remove static and have functional solution for the end. Or you can make sqLiteBase static.
private static SQLiteBase sqLiteBase;

Comment: Wow it was so obvious, how did I miss that... well i'll delete the question since it will be no use to anyone I believe, thanks for the help !

Comment: You welcome :) Take care of static things, they can make many problems.